# node.js app runs from command line but gives errors when run from cron job on reboot on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: bash, cron, nodejs

When starting my app manually using forever, it works fine. It runs on localhost:8080 and `nginx` does the routing.

When using a `cronjob` my `starter.sh` script runs but in the forever log I get an error. If I run the `starter.sh` script from the command line my app also works. It only does not work when run from a `cronjob`. Here are the details:

forever list command output:

```
data:    [0] pQHz /root/.nvm/v0.10.26/bin/node server.js 953     1077 /root/.forever/pQHz.log 0:0:0:7.90
```

`starter.sh` bash script that runs on reboot:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $(ps -e -o uid,cmd | grep $UID | grep node | grep -v grep | wc -l | tr -s "\n") -eq 0 ]
then
        export PATH=/root/.nvm/v0.10.26/bin/:$PATH
        forever start --spinSleepTime 10000 --sourceDir /root/neet server.js  >> /root/cronlog.txt 2>&1
fi
```

`crontab -e`:

```
@reboot sh /root/neet/starter.sh
```

`starter.sh` output:

```
^[[33mwarn^[[39m:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
^[[32minfo^[[39m:    Forever processing file: ^[[90mserver.js^[[39m
```

forever ERROR log:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory './client/index.html'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
    at self.populateCache (/root/neet/server.js:42:40)
    at self.initialize (/root/neet/server.js:174:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/neet/server.js:191:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
error: Script restart attempt #1
```

This is the line of code in my app that the error references:

```
self.zcache['index.html'] = fs.readFileSync('./client/index.html');
```

I'm really stumped as to why it can't read the file only when running from a `cronjob` on reboot. Some help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: self.zcache['index.html'] = fs.readFileSync('./client/index.html');

should be

    self.zcache['index.html'] = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/client/index.html');

Comment: you might want to see the solution in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600943/fs-readfilesync-is-not-file-relative-node-js

Answer (score 1):

When your running the script from cron, your current working directory will be the home directory of user who the script is called for. So when your script is trying to find the relative path ./client/index.html the file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to configure it in a version independent way (you probably have multiple node versions installed since you are using nvm).

This is the same snippet that the nvm-installer adds to your /root/.bashrc script

```
@doc Required to enable node/nvm for a cronjob ()

@doc  cron uses by default a short PATH = /usr/bin:/bin and does not execute /root/.bashrc (equal to /root/.bashrc)

@doc  nvm (node version manager) does not configure itself in a crontab job (that is only done for interactive shells in my /root/.bashrc).

export NVM_DIR="/root/.nvm"  # or perhaps ~./nvm in your environment.
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```